# PHP Include files by a function

Tags: php, function, file, include

Is it possible to include a file using a function in PHP? I've already tried something but the file is not included in the script.

I'm using this function :

```
function run($entry_point){
    if(!empty($entry_point)){
        if(file_exists('assets/controllers/'.$entry_point.'.php'))
            include 'assets/controllers/'.$entry_point.'.php';
        else
            include 'assets/controllers/home.php';
    }
}
```

My problem its that with this kind of function the index won't include the `$entry_point` file.

`Index.php` code:

```
session_start();
run($_GET['location']);
```

Thanks!

Comment: `is it possible to include a file using a function in PHP?` Yes

Comment: "*If the include occurs inside a function within the calling file, then all of the code contained in the called file will behave as though it had been defined inside that function.*" [source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Comment: Ok, so its there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: The best way is to use an autoloader.... google [PSR 0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) or [PSR 4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) (depending on whether you're using namespaces or not) or [spl_autoload](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload.php)

Answer (score 0):

First of all: your function works for me. Make sure that the names of the folders are correct and turn on error reporting (`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set("display_errors", 1);`).

There are different ways to include files dynamically into your script.

Common frameworks use stuff like (a bit modified for your case):

```
function includeScript($path = 'assets/controllers/',$file = 'home'){
    require $path . $file . '.php';
}
```

If you're including classes, consider using an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php):

```
function my_autoloader($class) {
    include 'assets/controllers/' . $class . '.php';
}

spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
```

What this would do is, that whenever you want to use a class that is not defined, it would automatically look for a file named like the class in the `assets/controllers/` folder. E.g:

```
// the autoloader would look for assets/controllers/Class1.php
$obj = new Class1();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) will be the ideal candidate for this. However, your function looks fine to me.
Can you make following amendments to the script ?

1. Turn on error reporting and also display the errors. Refer to Mark's answer for details.
2. Add __ DIR __ constant before 'assets. So the line will become :

   if(file_exists(__ DIR __.'/assets/controllers/'.$entry_point.'.php'))
           include __ DIR __.'/assets/controllers/'.$entry_point.'.php';
       else
           include __ DIR __.'/assets/controllers/home.php';

P.S. : Please use braces for conditional logic. It makes code more readable.